# Accept Facebook non-discrimination policy with System User

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

When I'm trying to validate or create my ad using **System User** access token, I'm getting this message:

> It looks like you have not yet certified that you'll comply with
>   our non-discrimination policy. To continue advertising, click here
>   to certify compliance with our non-discrimination policy.

I have already accept this non-discrimination policy but from my Facebook Account. But I'm still having the same error message.

My question is, is there a way to accept this policy from the **System user** using Facebook API or something else?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to “Review...” on section 1 from this link. Then you will see “I accept” bottom, press it.

Link from facebook official :
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/338925176776440?helpref=uf_permalink